# Trying to call a function in an "if... else..." statement, and its saying that the function below isn't defined

Tags: python, function, while-loop, function-definition

```
y = 0
x = 10

print("TRUE" if y>x else theloop())

def theloop():
 while y < 11:
    print(f"Number is {y}!")
    y = y + 1
```

I want y to keep on getting bigger by 1 until it becomes bigger than x and print "TRUE", but each time it keeps saying the function isn't defined.

I tried this right here and it seems to work for some reason. But whenever I want y to increase by 1, it completely stops working.

```
y=0
x=10

def theloop():
    while y < x:
       print(y+1)

print("true" if y>x else theloop())
```

Comment: "But whenever I want y to increase by 1, it completely stops working." - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-trying-to-use-a-variable-supposed-to-be-global-that-is-rea

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "completely stops working" means.

Comment: When you do `y = y + 1` you're shadowing the global variable `y` with a new local variable `y`.  You can "fix" this by saying `global y` at the start of the function to say that you want local assignments to affect the global variable -- but once you learn about objects, you should put this state into an object and make `theloop` a method of that object instead of having global functions that modify global state.

Comment: You're calling `theloop()` before it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

## First thing:

In the global scope, you want to define a function before you call it.
This explains why your first code doesn't work. Python hasn't defined the function yet and you're calling it before it has a chance to access it.

```py
print("TRUE" if y>x else theloop())

# Python hasn't seen this when you call the function
def theloop():
    while y < x:
       print(y+1)
```

## Second thing:

The code you wrote that runs only prints (y+1)... it does **not** actually increase y by 1.

Also, y is not accessible within the function so:

### Define it locally before the while loop like this:

```py
x = 10

def the_loop():
    # define y locally
    y = 0
    while y < x:
        # increases y by 1
        y += 1
        print(y)

print("true" if y > x else the_loop())
```

### Pass it in as an argument if y might change:

```py
x = 10
y = 0

# pass y in as an argument 
def the_loop(y):
    while y < x:
        # increases y by 1
        y += 1
        print(y)

print("true" if y > x else the_loop(y))
```

### Use the global keyword (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function))

```py
y = 0
x = 10

def theloop():
    global y
    while y < x:
       y += 1
       print(y)

print("true" if y > x else the_loop())
```

Using global keyword actually changes the original variable and now y = 10 is accessible outside of the function.
[More on globals here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)

Comment: Have you tried this code?  I don't think it will work.

Comment: @MarkRansom Fixed it, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Worth noting that in the second version, the global `y` remains 0 even after it's been incremented inside `the_loop`.